# How would you interpret the pattern in this picture? (generated by re-sorting pixels based on their RGB value)

Tags: image-processing, filters, filter-design, sampling, computer-vision

Was playing with some pictures and ran the ruby code below. The code reads an input image using the ImageMagick library, gets an array of pixels, re-sorts the pixels and then writes out an image with the re-sorted pixels and using the same dimensions as the original image.

```
require 'rmagick'

include Magick

img = ImageList.new("images/test-image.jpg")
pixels = img.get_pixels(0,0,img.columns,img.rows)

# Sort pixels by total intensity

# https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sort
# The block must implement a comparison between a and b and
# * <0 when b follows a,
# * 0 when a and b are equivalent, 
# * >0 when a follows b

# The result is not guaranteed to be stable.
# When the comparison of two elements returns 0, the order of the elements is unpredictable.

pixels = pixels.sort {|p| p.red + p.green + p.blue}

out_img = Magick::Image.new(img.columns, img.rows)
out_img.store_pixels(0,0, img.columns, img.rows, pixels)
out_img.write("images/test-image-out.jpg")
```

I was trying to sort the pixels by the sum of their RGB values, but for that I should have used `sort_by` instead of `sort` on the pixels array.

So the pixels are not being sorted by the sum of their RGB values, but **I don't know how they are being sorted either, and why when sorted that way they generate the pattern on the sample pictures below**.

I included the short documentation of the Ruby `Array.sort` method to help understand with what's going on.

Original picture:
[image]

Picture with re-ordered pixels (using `pixels.sort {|p| p.red + p.green + p.blue}` or `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| 1}`):
[image]

Following suggestions from @OlliNiemitalo and @xiota, if instead of doing `pixels = pixels.sort {|p| p.red + p.green + p.blue}` the code does `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| 1}`, the output is the same (the weird repetition pattern).

When doing `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| b <=> a}` though, the output looks like the picture below.

[image]

Below is what happens when running `(0..1023).to_a.sort{|p| 1}` on the irb (ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin16]). Can't really tell what the pattern is just by looking at the numbers.

```
irb(main):009:0> (0..1023).to_a.sort{|p| 1}
=> [22, 512, 0, 513, 1, 514, 2, 515, 3, 516, 4, 517, 25, 518, 29, 519, 33, 520, 40, 41, 275, 787, 147, 659, 403, 915, 83, 595, 339, 723, 211, 851, 467, 979, 51, 563, 307, 627, 179, 691, 371, 755, 115, 819, 435, 883, 243, 947, 499, 1011, 15, 547, 291, 579, 163, 611, 323, 643, 99, 675, 355, 707, 195, 739, 387, 771, 67, 803, 419, 835, 227, 867, 451, 899, 131, 931, 483, 963, 259, 995, 18, 523, 7, 539, 283, 555, 155, 571, 299, 587, 91, 603, 315, 619, 171, 635, 331, 651, 59, 667, 347, 683, 187, 699, 363, 715, 107, 731, 379, 747, 203, 763, 395, 779, 43, 795, 411, 811, 219, 827, 427, 843, 123, 859, 443, 875, 235, 891, 459, 907, 75, 923, 475, 939, 251, 955, 491, 971, 139, 987, 507, 1003, 267, 1019, 271, 527, 27, 535, 279, 543, 151, 551, 287, 559, 87, 567, 295, 575, 159, 583, 303, 591, 55, 599, 311, 607, 167, 615, 319, 623, 95, 631, 327, 639, 175, 647, 335, 655, 30, 663, 343, 671, 183, 679, 351, 687, 103, 695, 359, 703, 191, 711, 367, 719, 63, 727, 375, 735, 199, 743, 383, 751, 111, 759, 391, 767, 207, 775, 399, 783, 11, 791, 407, 799, 215, 807, 415, 815, 119, 823, 423, 831, 223, 839, 431, 847, 71, 855, 439, 863, 231, 871, 447, 879, 127, 887, 455, 895, 239, 903, 463, 911, 47, 919, 471, 927, 247, 935, 479, 943, 135, 951, 487, 959, 255, 967, 495, 975, 79, 983, 503, 991, 263, 999, 511, 1007, 143, 1015, 36, 1023, 145, 525, 273, 529, 35, 533, 277, 537, 149, 541, 281, 545, 85, 549, 285, 553, 153, 557, 289, 561, 53, 565, 293, 569, 157, 573, 297, 577, 89, 581, 301, 585, 161, 589, 305, 593, 17, 597, 309, 601, 165, 605, 313, 609, 93, 613, 317, 617, 169, 621, 321, 625, 57, 629, 325, 633, 173, 637, 329, 641, 97, 645, 333, 649, 177, 653, 337, 657, 9, 661, 341, 665, 181, 669, 345, 673, 101, 677, 349, 681, 185, 685, 353, 689, 61, 693, 357, 697, 189, 701, 361, 705, 105, 709, 365, 713, 193, 717, 369, 721, 39, 725, 373, 729, 197, 733, 377, 737, 109, 741, 381, 745, 201, 749, 385, 753, 65, 757, 389, 761, 205, 765, 393, 769, 113, 773, 397, 777, 209, 781, 401, 785, 5, 789, 405, 793, 213, 797, 409, 801, 117, 805, 413, 809, 217, 813, 417, 817, 69, 821, 421, 825, 221, 829, 425, 833, 121, 837, 429, 841, 225, 845, 433, 849, 45, 853, 437, 857, 229, 861, 441, 865, 125, 869, 445, 873, 233, 877, 449, 881, 73, 885, 453, 889, 237, 893, 457, 897, 129, 901, 461, 905, 241, 909, 465, 913, 13, 917, 469, 921, 245, 925, 473, 929, 133, 933, 477, 937, 249, 941, 481, 945, 77, 949, 485, 953, 253, 957, 489, 961, 137, 965, 493, 969, 257, 973, 497, 977, 49, 981, 501, 985, 261, 989, 505, 993, 141, 997, 509, 1001, 265, 1005, 20, 1009, 81, 1013, 28, 1017, 269, 1021, 37, 522, 82, 524, 272, 526, 146, 528, 274, 530, 521, 532, 276, 534, 148, 536, 278, 538, 84, 540, 280, 542, 150, 544, 282, 546, 52, 548, 284, 550, 152, 552, 286, 554, 86, 556, 288, 558, 154, 560, 290, 562, 16, 564, 292, 566, 156, 568, 294, 570, 88, 572, 296, 574, 158, 576, 298, 578, 54, 580, 300, 582, 160, 584, 302, 586, 90, 588, 304, 590, 162, 592, 306, 594, 8, 596, 308, 598, 164, 600, 310, 602, 92, 604, 312, 606, 166, 608, 314, 610, 56, 612, 316, 614, 168, 616, 318, 618, 94, 620, 320, 622, 170, 624, 322, 626, 26, 628, 324, 630, 172, 632, 326, 634, 96, 636, 328, 638, 174, 640, 330, 642, 58, 644, 332, 646, 176, 648, 334, 650, 98, 652, 336, 654, 178, 656, 338, 658, 23, 660, 340, 662, 180, 664, 342, 666, 100, 668, 344, 670, 182, 672, 346, 674, 60, 676, 348, 678, 184, 680, 350, 682, 102, 684, 352, 686, 186, 688, 354, 690, 34, 692, 356, 694, 188, 696, 358, 698, 104, 700, 360, 702, 190, 704, 362, 706, 62, 708, 364, 710, 192, 712, 366, 714, 106, 716, 368, 718, 194, 720, 370, 722, 10, 724, 372, 726, 196, 728, 374, 730, 108, 732, 376, 734, 198, 736, 378, 738, 64, 740, 380, 742, 200, 744, 382, 746, 110, 748, 384, 750, 202, 752, 386, 754, 42, 756, 388, 758, 204, 760, 390, 762, 112, 764, 392, 766, 206, 768, 394, 770, 66, 772, 396, 774, 208, 776, 398, 778, 114, 780, 400, 782, 210, 784, 402, 786, 31, 788, 404, 790, 212, 792, 406, 794, 116, 796, 408, 798, 214, 800, 410, 802, 68, 804, 412, 806, 216, 808, 414, 810, 118, 812, 416, 814, 218, 816, 418, 818, 44, 820, 420, 822, 220, 824, 422, 826, 120, 828, 424, 830, 222, 832, 426, 834, 70, 836, 428, 838, 224, 840, 430, 842, 122, 844, 432, 846, 226, 848, 434, 850, 12, 852, 436, 854, 228, 856, 438, 858, 124, 860, 440, 862, 230, 864, 442, 866, 72, 868, 444, 870, 232, 872, 446, 874, 126, 876, 448, 878, 234, 880, 450, 882, 46, 884, 452, 886, 236, 888, 454, 890, 128, 892, 456, 894, 238, 896, 458, 898, 74, 900, 460, 902, 240, 904, 462, 906, 130, 908, 464, 910, 242, 912, 466, 914, 6, 916, 468, 918, 244, 920, 470, 922, 132, 924, 472, 926, 246, 928, 474, 930, 76, 932, 476, 934, 248, 936, 478, 938, 134, 940, 480, 942, 250, 944, 482, 946, 48, 948, 484, 950, 252, 952, 486, 954, 136, 956, 488, 958, 254, 960, 490, 962, 78, 964, 492, 966, 256, 968, 494, 970, 138, 972, 496, 974, 258, 976, 498, 978, 14, 980, 500, 982, 260, 984, 502, 986, 140, 988, 504, 990, 262, 992, 506, 994, 80, 996, 508, 998, 264, 1000, 510, 1002, 142, 1004, 21, 1006, 266, 1008, 19, 1010, 50, 1012, 24, 1014, 268, 1016, 32, 1018, 144, 1020, 38, 1022, 270, 531]
```

As per @xiota's additional suggestion, running `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| a <=> b}` creates a sort of "reverse" image of the one generated with `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| b <=> a}` (notice the change of a and b's position when being compared). Here's the output:

[image: Another image]

Comment: I wonder if you get the same result from `pixels = pixels.sort {|p| 1}`.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo yes, I get the same result using that line :)

Comment: What happens if you put `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| 1}` ?  What about `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| b <=> a}` ?

Comment: @xiota thank you for the help in trying to figure this out. This line `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| 1}` generates the same pattern as `pixels.sort {|p| p.red + p.green + p.blue}` in the output picture. The line `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| 1}` generates a different pattern (you can see the corresponding picture on the question now).

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo figured out that the pattern is generated by the quicksort algorithm implementation of ruby. but I'm still unable to conceptually explain/understand how it works in relation to what the picture looks like. What would be a more semantical (less procedural) explanation? What additional meaning could be assigned to this?

Comment: @NicoBrenner try sorting something simpler like `(0..1023).to_a.sort{|p| 1}`. In case of `ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]` it just reverses the order, but perhaps on your platform something different takes place.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo `(0..1023).to_a.sort{|p| 1}` does something different on my computer, the full result is part of the question now. There seem to be some sequences, but I can't identify a clear pattern in the numbers after being sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In support of `Comparable` mixin, a default `<=>` or [spaceship operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison) for pixels is defined in the function `Pixel_spaceship` in [`rmpixel.c`](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/blob/master/ext/RMagick/rmpixel.c). However, in your use of the `sort` method, you define your own code block that overrides the `<=>` operator, and yours takes a single argument rather than two [which would be correct](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sort), so the definition is broken and will not work correctly in sorting. The undefined sorting result will depend on the sorting algorithm used. Ruby sorts arrays using the [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm, which is a [divide-and-conquer algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm), dividing the problem into progressively smaller sub-problems. You can see this behavior in your output image, which I think is an artifact from using Quicksort with a broken `<=>` operator.

On some computing platforms, Ruby uses the platform's Quicksort implementation (see `rb_sort` in [`array.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/array.c) and `ruby_qsort` in [`util.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/util.c)), so the undefined results also vary depending on the platform, as demonstrated in comments to the question. See `util.c` for Ruby's own Quicksort implementation. For someone who wants to take the time to tackle this, you'd replace each `<=>` comparison by constant `1`, and simplify the code.

Let's plot the question's `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin16]` platform "sorted" `0..1023` test data (labeled Source #) as function of position, using | markers to more clearly see step sizes:

[image]

Ignoring small-scale detail, as if we were looking at a very large image from a very large distance, we can deduce that with $n=0,1,2,3,\ldots$, each $2$nd $1/(n+2)$ part of the output image is an additive mixture of scaled parts of the input image:

- the $2$nd $1/2$ part of the image enlarged by a factor of $2^{-n}$ with mixing weight $1/2$,
- the $2$nd $1/4$ part of the image enlarged by a factor of $2^{1-n}$ with mixing weight $1/4$,
- the $2$nd $1/8$ part of the image enlarged by a factor of $2^{2-n}$ with mixing weight $1/8$,
- the $2$nd $1/16$ part of the image enlarged by a factor of $2^{3-n}$ with mixing weight $1/16$,
- ... (until the part size goes to zero).

Here, *enlarged by a factor of $2^x$* means that if $x < 1$ then the image part in question is reduced in size by factor $2^{-x}$ and replicated (tiled), and if $x > 1$, then the image part is enlarged by factor $2^x$ and the $2^x$ enlarged $1/2^x$ sub-parts are additively mixed with equal weight $1/2^x$.

The small-scale detail ignored in this analysis is the interlacing, which from a large distance looks like additive mixing. Also some unexplained details that don't seem to scale with the data size are ignored.

Here is a Python script (sorry, I don't know Ruby) that reproduces most of the aesthetic qualities of the picture, not by using the above analysis but by mimicking the interlacing in the plot above:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get("https://i.stack.imgur.com/T520A.jpg")
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
pix = img.load()
w, h = img.size
pix_flat = []
for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        pix_flat.append(pix[x, y])

for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        if (x > 0 or y > 0):  # Do not touch pix[0, 0]
            i = x + w*y     
            j = i
            while j < w*h//2:
                j *= 2
            k = i
            while k & 1:
                j >>= 1
                k >>= 1
            pix[x, y] = pix_flat[j]

img.save("output.jpg", "JPEG")
```

Result #1:

[image]

We can get rid of the vertical striping by replacing the interlacing by weighted summation in a linear color space, assuming that the source image is in sRGB color space, in Python:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get("https://i.stack.imgur.com/T520A.jpg")
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
pix = img.load()
w, h = img.size

# These originate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472375/linear-to-srgb-conversion
def srgb2lin(s):  
    if s <= 0.0404482362771082:
        lin = s / 12.92
    else:
        lin = pow(((s + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
    return lin

def lin2srgb(lin):
    if lin > 0.0031308:
        s = 1.055 * (pow(lin, (1.0 / 2.4))) - 0.055
    else:
        s = 12.92 * lin
    return s

pix_flat_lin = []
for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        pix_flat_lin.append([srgb2lin(pix[x, y][k]/255) for k in range(3)])

for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        if (x > 0 or y > 0):  # Do not touch pix[0, 0]
            i = x + w*y     
            j = i
            while j < w*h//2:
                j *= 2
            pixel_lin = [pix_flat_lin[j][k] * 0.5 for k in range(3)]
            j >>= 1
            m = 0.25
            while j:
                pixel_lin = [pixel_lin[k] + pix_flat_lin[j][k] * m for k in range(3)]
                j >>= 1
                m *= 0.5
            pix[x, y] = tuple([int(round(lin2srgb(pixel_lin[k])*255)) for k in range(3)])
    print(str(y+1)+"/"+str(h))

img.save("output2.jpg", "JPEG")
```

Result #2:

[image]

This still has the horizontal stripes.

Comment: That's a very well researched and insightful answer! And makes a lot of sense that the sorting algorithm itself is being "reflected"/"imprinted" in the picture. Cool, thank you :)

Comment: So, if you wanted to generate the picture with the artifacts on purpose, without using the broken Quicksort, how would you do it?

Comment: Do you mean to include also the small-scale details of the artifact (also in the bottom half)? That would sound difficult.

Comment: Ideally yes, create the same image. Alternatively, how would you explain the way the pixels of the picture end up getting arranged and why those same pixels that create one big image can also create several similar smaller copies of the image, regardless of the image?

Comment: Loved the plot with the numbers from 0 to 1023, its very cool to see how the numbers are being distributed. Any ideas on how to do the inverse of what quicksort is doing with the data? ie. if you only had the output image, how would you put the original image back together?

Comment: You could "sort" `(0..width*height-1)`, and then put the pixels to the places pointed out by that list.

Comment: would it be right to interpret that as creating a map of the effect of the sorting algorithm and then using that map "in reverse" to "place back" the pixels in the "original" place?

Comment: @NicoBrenner yes.

Comment: Thank you. Both you Olli Niemitalo, and @xiota have been amazingly insightful and patient. I'm super thankful for the time and enthusiasm you have put into figuring this out. ❤️

Comment: Cool you created a Python version! Super impressed with your analysis and the code. In the last image, is part of the information (the striping) being discarded? Would that prevent the reconstruction of the original image from the "scrambled" one?

Comment: That is correct, at least if attempting the reconstruction by pixel reordering. Neither is result #1 guaranteed to not duplicate pixels. I was aiming for similar aesthetics only.

Comment: Well, you did a great job with the aesthetics, it looks great.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Ruby programmer, so there will be a lot of *handwaving* in this answer. If you are particularly concerned about skipped details, you'll have to look in the Ruby source code.

- In `array.sort {|a,b| a <=> b}`, the `sort` method of `array` is being called with a block `{ ... }`. The arguments used by the block are given by `|a,b|`. The comparison "spaceship" operator is `a <=> b`. It returns 1, 0, -1, depending on whether `a` is "larger" than `b`.
- In the code you wrote, `pixels = pixels.sort {|p| p.red + p.green + p.blue}`, you are adding three positive integers. The result is another positive integer that is interpreted as `1`. So `sort` behaves as if the comparison is *always* evaluating as "larger". Instead of separating, or recombining, values into arrays based on size, as you would expect `sort` to behave, they are split based on the order in which they appeared in the original array.

  This causes smaller *copies* of the original image to be created when every other pixel is put into a different array. This is repeated for every array, until we're down to pairs. The arrays are then merged back together to get the result you see. (This is a major *handwaving* checkpoint. You'll have to look at the sort implementation to see exactly how the arrays are merged.)
- The output ends up looking the same as either of the following. It doesn't matter if you have `|p|` or `|a,b|` because the arguments are ignored.

  ```
  pixels = pixels.sort {|p| 1}
  pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| 1}
  ```

  [image: weird]
- To get the result you're seeking, you can use:

  ```
  pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| (a.red + a.green + a.blue) <=> (b.red + b.green + b.blue)}
  ```

  [image: desired result]
- The default `Pixel_spaceship` operator that [Olli Niemitalo](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/60107/44670) mentions is different from the function you intend, so `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| a <=> b}` has a striped appearance. Using `b <=> a` will reverse the order.

  [image: a <=> b]

Comment: `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| (a.red + a.green + a.blue) <=> (b.red + b.green + b.blue)}` generates this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WwpX.jpg

Comment: added the image for `pixels = pixels.sort {|a,b| a <=> b}` on the question. It looks like a "reverse" or flipped version of the previous one (`b <=> a`)

Comment: This answers what puzzled me about the output you were getting. If you want more details about what's happening *inside* sort, looks like Olli Niemitalo is willing to get into it.

Comment: @xiota not really :D but I did analyze the effective result.